# Fix Image Position

Tags: html, css, image, position, fixed

I have limited knowledge around this, hence why I am probably struggling.

I am trying to add an image that will link to a twitter account within a bio using the following code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/UserName" target="_blank">
<img style="position:absolute;left:33.75%;bottom:-71.5%; width:65px; height:65px;" 
src="https://i.imgur.com/AAA111.jpg" target="_blank"></a>
```

This works perfectly fine but only if Chrome on my monitor is maximised. If I go on a different computer or make the window smaller etc the image does not stay in a fixed position and instead will move to a random spot on the page.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where should it be located, roughly? Like top-left-ish? or bottom-left-ish? Also, could you give more code, so we can have more context? Or maybe even an image of what you need?

Comment: It should be positioned slightly up and to the left of centre. There isn’t more code to it, it’s literallt just an image of the Twitter icon that will be located in the about me page of a bio which, when you click the icon, will take you to the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code snippet below, the image will be centered horizontally and vertically on the screen regardless of the screen size. You can just the positioning of the image with the CSS below. With this setup, no matter where you position the image, it should stay ***mostly*** in that position regardless of the screen size.

You can test my code by running the snippet, making it full screen and playing with the screen size. The image will always stay in the center. Again you can adjust the values to adjust the position to how you need it. Hope this helps!

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper img {
  width: 65px;
  height: auto; /* Or 65px, whatever you need it to be. */
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* This will place it in the middle */
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/UserName" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AAA111.jpg" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You try %
Change height:50% and width:50%
`<a href="https://twitter.com/UserName" target="_blank">
<img style="position:absolute;left:33.75%;bottom:-71.5%; width:50%; height:50%" 
src="https://i.imgur.com/AAA111.jpg" target="_blank"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

This means that it is not responsive.
Try adding media queries for the image

Example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  img{
    width:50%
     height: 50%
  }
}
```